# Selecting point feature on Mouse click using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

How do I select point feature on mouse click?

I can select polygon feature but I cannot select apoint feature.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IIdentify identifyLayer = (IIdentify)iLayer;
IArray array = identifyLayer.Identify(identifyPoint);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to convert your clicked point into map coordinates, on your event the X and Y are screen coordinates which need to be converted with [IDisplayTransformation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000s1000000):

In your OnMouseDown event:

```
IPoint pQueryPoint = new PointClass();
pQueryPoint = gDoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y);
```

gDoc is of type [IMxDocument](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v0000010w000000). Then buffer the query point to a query geometry, this example is in pixels to *map coordinates*:

```
int PxTol = 6; // 6 pixels to select by
IPoint pNextPoint = gDoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X + PxTol, arg.Y);
double pSrchDist = pNextPoint.X - pQueryPoint.X; // measure the distance between points PxTol apart
ITopologicalOperator pTopOp = (ITopologicalOperator)pQueryPoint;
IGeometry pSrchGeom = pTopOp.Buffer(pSrchDist);
```

If your feature class has a spatial reference other than the [FocusMap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v0000011t000000) you will need to [project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000020r000000) the points first before creating the buffer. Then setup a spatial filter:

```
ISpatialFilter pSF = new SpatialFilterClass();
pSF.Geometry = pSrchGeom;
pSF.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
```

Now [search](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Search_Method/0025000002t9000000/) from the ILayer as IFeatureLayer to return a cursor:

```
IFeatureCursor pDestCur = (YourLayer as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass.Search(pSF, true); 
// recycling cursor, use non-recycling if you're going to modify any part of the feature
```

which you can iterate through:

```
IFeature pFeat = pDestCur.NextFeature();

do
{
    // do something with pFeat
    pFeat = pDestCur.NextFeature();
} while (pFeat != null);
```

Or you can [select](http://IFeatureClass.Select) to get an ISelectionSet:

```
ISelectionSet pSelSet = (YourLayer as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass.Select(
pSF,
esriSelectionType.esriSelectionTypeHybrid,
esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionNormal,
YourWorkspace);
```

Comment: I could select point feature.. thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post much code but I'm going to assume that identifyPoint is an IPoint in map coordinates.

```
IGeometry buffer = (identifyPoint as ITopologicalOperator).Buffer(1);
map.SelectByShape(buffer, null, true);
```

First you buffer the point you are using to search. The buffer will be in the units of the current geometry. So if I'm in UTM, the buffer would buffer 1 meter out. ([doc](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/ITopologicalOperator_Buffer.htm))

Now I can take my current map and use select by shape. This will select anything within the buffer that is currently on the map. ([doc](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IMap_SelectByShape.htm))